# What changes have been made to bash in Lion?

Tags: macos, bash

I am working on some `bash` shell scripting for a local login script and it works fine on Leopard and Snow Leopard but fails on Lion.  I was curious if there was a place that listed the differences in `bash` on Lion?

Comment: This is a very, very vague question. You'd do best to post all or a portion of the script and explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: I do not think that it required a down vote.  Surely there is a way to tell what differences exist in BASH between the versions.

Comment: I was trying to use the following variable in my bash script:    username="$(whoami)"

Comment: @John I tried `u="$(whoami)"; echo $u` on 10.6 and 10.7, with the same result. Post the script source, that way you'll get decent answers. Also, to address your main question, the latest system upgrades for 10.7 and 10.6 will have the same version of bash anyway, ie. `3.2.48(1)-release`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within bash, the command `echo $BASH_VERSION` shows the version of bash. You can then look up what changed in the [changelog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Changelog) file, which is bash's case is called [`CHANGES`](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/CHANGES). (There's a more complete changelog in the sources, but it's mainly of interest to people who write and maintain bash.)

If your machines are up-to-date, [they'll be running the same version](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30096/bash-differences-from-snow-leopard-to-lion/30100#30100). Make sure all the external programs used in the script are up-to-date too: the script may behave differently because one of these programs produces different output.

You can watch what your script is doing more closely by running `bash -x /path/to/script`. The `-x` option makes bash print a trace for each command that it runs. You can also put `set -x` in a script to turn tracing on, and `set +x` to turn it off.

Comment: `bash --version` will give you the same result as `echo $BASH_VERSION` btw. +1 for `bash -x script`

Answer (score 7):

Assuming a SnowLeopard or Lion installation that has the latest software updates, the version of Bash is the same. `3.2.48(1)-release`.

On SnowLeopard you may have a 32bit compilation in some cases, whereas on Lion it is (by default) 64bit.

The command `username="$(whoami)"` is *extemely* unlikely to ever change it's output on bash, since doing so would incur the fast moving, brain devouring wrath of an infinite number of ravenous zombie sysadmin types.

<sup>(By the way sysadmins are almost never undead, despite the occasional appearance to the contrary. The description was added for dramatic effect, and no offence to sysadmins was intended. I offer my heartfelt apology to any actual undead sysadmins, and their families, and I urge them to grab a shotgun immediately and barricade the bedroom door, double tap to be sure.)</sup>